# error C2039 in class-templates function-template type resolution

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Why the error `"Error   C2039   'T': is not a member of 'B'"` occurs having A definitely the member of B? Is there not less general workaround?

The IDE is Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.7.4

Minimal example to reproduce my issue:

```
// reproduce_2039.cpp
//

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    void s(){
        cout << "a::s()" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public virtual A {

};

template<typename D>
class M {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void set() {
        typedef D::T T1;
        auto f = &(T1::s);
        vector<decltype(f)> v;
        v.push_back(f);
        cout << v.size() << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    M<B> m;
    m.set<A>();    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef D::T T1;
```

when `D` is `B` will look for `T` in `B` which doesn't exist.

Since you also want to make a pointer to the member `s`, it looks like you want:

```cpp
typedef T T1;
auto f = &T1::s;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Though your solution obviously works in context of my shortened example, it also works with my specifics: I was thinking pointer-to-base-member-function is not applicable to derived object instance, but it is.

Comment: @YaroslavYamshchikov Glad it helped! You're welcome!